# cant get text from span with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Why can I not get the text `3.7M` from those (multiple with same class name) `span` with below code?:

```
result_prices_pc = soup.find_all("span", attrs={"class": "pc_color font-weight-bold"})
```

HTML:

```
<td><span class="pc_color font-weight-bold">3.7M <img alt="c" class="small-coins-icon" src="/design/img/coins_bin.png"></span></td>
```

I try to get all prices with a for loop:

```
for price in result_prices_pc:
    print(price.text)
```

But I cant get the text from it.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: sure: https://www.futbin.com/players

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" is the `pc_color` CSS class. When you load the page, you need to specify what version of page do you need (PS4/XBOX/PC) - this is done by "platform" cookie (or you can use `ps4_color` instead of `pc_color`, for example):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.futbin.com/players"
cookies = {"platform": "pc"}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, cookies=cookies).content, "html.parser")


result_prices_pc = soup.find_all(
    "span", attrs={"class": "pc_color font-weight-bold"}
)

for price in result_prices_pc:
    print(price.text)
```

Prints:

```
0 
1.15M 
3.75M 
1.7M 
4.19M 
1.81M 
351.65K 
0 
1.66M 
98K 
1.16M 
3M 
775K 
99K 
1.62M 
187K 
280K 
245K 
220K 
1.03M 
395K 
100K 
185K 
864.2K 
0 
1.95M 
540K 
0 
0 
89K
```

Answer (score 1):

These elements are actually having multiple class names: `pc_color font-weight-bold` are actually `pc_color` and `font-weight-bold` class names.
Forthis case you should use this syntax:

```
result_prices_pc = soup.find_all("span", attrs={"class": ['pc_color', 'font-weight-bold']})
```